# "I did my best to do something" or "I did my best doing something"?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I wonder which case the gerund or infinitive is (more) appropriate here: "I did my best to do something" or "I did my best doing something"?

Answer (score 6):

Your first example is idiomatic.

> I did my best to do this. ... *It means “I tried as hard as I could to accomplish this”—regardless of whether you actually **did** accomplish it.*

Your second example is not idiomatic, but it is very close to a different idiom.

> I did my best **in** doing this. ... *It means “This was the best work I had ever done”—you achieved a new level of excellence.*

Comment: Right. _Do one's best to VP_ is idiomatic and means 'try (hard) to VP', but, like _try_, it does not imply that one actually succeeded in VP-ing. _Do one's best VP-ing,_ on the other hand, is compositional and merely means 'do one's best while/during/in VP-ing', and it **does** imply that one succeeded in VP-ing, and did rather well, in fact.